# How to print an error message when a user enters two options using getopt in c programming instead of one?

Tags: c, getopt

The user gives an option. If he enters `-d -e` both together it should print an error message saying `-d` and `-e` cannot be set together and then exit.

```
while ( ( option = getopt (argc, argv, "hd:e:") ) != -1 ){

    switch ( option ) {

        case 'd':
        dflag = 1;
        key = optarg;
        break;

        case 'e':
        eflag = 1;
        key = optarg;
        break;

        case 'h':
        hflag = 1;
        break;

        default:
        perror ( "" );
        printf("default\n");
        display_usage ( argv [0] , OPTIONS );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );

    } /* end switch */
} /* end while */
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `while` block, add:

```
if (dflag && eflag) {
    printf("error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also, ensure that `dflag` , `eflag` and the other variables (as needed) are initialized to 0 before entering the `while` loop.

Comment: Interestingly, if always *one* of these two options must be present, there even is a single test for that.